# Crystal Reports 2016 unable to read Access 2016 using OLE DB

Tags: crystal-reports, ms-access-2016

I recently upgraded Office to 2016 and I have upgraded Crystal Reports to 2016 as well. As a result, the crystal reports will no longer read the access database.

They were originally connecting just fine using a OLE DB connection type and the Microsoft Office 12 Access Database Engine.

I have reinstalled the Office 2007 connectivity tools and the 64bit Access Database Engine, but they still won't connect.

I've looked around on various forums to find a solution but everything refers to reinstalling the connectivity tools and/or the database engine.

[image: Crystal Reports Error Message]

Does anyone know of anything that might resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I shared this post with members of the Access development team (I work closely with them in my content work). They wanted me to ask the following questions for more information:
1. Does the ACCDB database open successfully when launched by Access? (We want to make sure there aren't other issues at play here.)
2. What is your version number, build, and bitness of Office? Look on the File tab.
3. Is there a chance of getting a copy of this database, with sensitive data purged out, for the engineering team to look at?

Comment: Hello, Jeff.  Thank you for your response.  In response to your questions: 1)The accdb file does open in Access and works correctly. 2) My Office is version Professional Plus 2016, MSO 16.4005.1000, 64 bit - I'm not finding anything specifically listed as the build, but it appears to be 1000. 3) I can send a copy of the db.  Where should I send it or is there a way to attach it to this thread?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information about your configuration. The engineering team is still very interested in trying to test out your scenario with your database on their development machines. For sending me a copy of the database, send me a message via the contact page on my website - AccessJunkie.com. I'll coordinate from there and then report back any findings here so the whole group can see the results of the testing.